# Android preview camera returning incomplete data array

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm attempting to do some image processing on images returned by the Android preview camera via onPreviewFrame.  This was working fine at sizes up to 1080 by 720, but I attempted to increase resolution to 1920 by 1080.  The result is that I end up with incomplete data, and attempting to process every pixel gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

The data of a 1920 by 1080 image has 2073600 pixels, but it appears that the data[] returned by onPreviewFrame is always of size 1382400, regardless of image resolution.

```
params.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);

mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            changeMag = 0;
            thisDiff = 0;
            diffPixels = 0;
            try {
                if (currentImage != null) {
                    lastImage = currentImage;
                }
                Log.e("CameraTest", "Incoming data array size is only " + data.length);
}
```

This logs "Incoming data array size is only 1382400" no matter what preview size I select.

Given that 1920 by 1080 is supposedly a supported size, is there any way to get back that data via onPreviewFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, 1920x1080 is not supported. If getSupportedPreviewSizes() list does include this resolution, this would not be the first time that a device report is incorrect. For example, Galaxy Nexus claims to support QVGA (320x240) preview, but it cannot deliver such image. setPreviewSize() + setParameters() continue correctly, and even getPreviewSize() reports the expected value. But the preview callback returns an image in size same as the size before setting this resolution.

So, I would expect that you really receive a 1280x720 picture, and can do nothing about it.

Note that it may still be possible to record 1920x1080 video on this device: video recorder may use a special mechanism which involves hardware encoder and often sends the camera data to this encoder without copying it to user space.

Comment: Thank you.  Two followup questions come to mind.  First - how did you find that 1920 is not supported?  I couldn't find an external list and the device does report it as supported.

Second - do you have any knowledge of a way to change the return size on data[], or otherwise recover it?  To my surprise, it appears that I'm not getting a smaller image format.  Instead, I'm getting as much of the 1920x1080 data as the data[] can hold, and the rest is being discarded.

I realize that this likely can't be done, but I'm tantalized by the fact that the image is being shot at that resolution.

Comment: 1. The procedure to determine that device X supports resolution Y is very straightforward: try to set resolution Y, and if you get the expected data on callback - then the answer is positive; otherwise - negative. That's exactly what you did. BTW, how do you know that you are getting _as much of the 1920x1080 data as the data[] can hold_? Which preview format did you use?

Comment: 2. No, this size is beyond your control. At any rate, we have entered the uncharted waters of a system with bugs in camera service, so anything could happen. E.g. using slightly different flow could make a difference.

Comment: This is an old issue, but I'll update for anyone curious in the future.

Comment: I know that the theoretical size of the image is larger than the max size of data[].  The invalid images seemingly come through with 1.5 color channels (full luma, plus a 'torn' chroma channel where a portion of the image is incompletely colored).

As for displaying a preview to the device screen, that doesn't pass through data[] and the image there is correct despite the corruption in the saved version.